# Bisect a curved plate always perpendicular to its direction

Tags: bisect

I have recently joined the Blender community and I am desperately in need of help :(.

I am currently trying to bisect this curved plate (no path is available). I want to bisect this plate every 20 meters of its length always perpendicular to the x vector of the curve.

Since the plate is curved this has proven to be quite a challenge.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Cheers.

[image]

Comment: Please add an image of what you have so far and what you need so that we have some idea of what you are talking about. You can use Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu to save an image and then follow https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post to add images to your question.